Moving images in subfolders based on orientation
I have the following script that moves portrait-orientation images to a subfolder named 'portrait'.
It works perfectly well but only if the script is located and executed from the same folder as the images. This means I have to copy the script to all my folders and run it once for every folder (painful!).
How can I modify the script so it can be located and executed from a parent folder and recurses any subfolders of images such as:
Folder (script is here)
SubFolder1 (images are here)
SubFolder2 (images are here)
SubFolder3 (images are here)

And results in:

Folder
SubFolder1\portrait (portrait images are moved here)
SubFolder2\portrait (portrait images are moved here)
SubFolder3\portrait (portrait images are moved here)

Script:
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$ImageList = Get-ChildItem "*.jp*g"
$LandscapePath = ""
$PortraitPath = "portrait"

md portrait

Foreach($ImageFile in $ImageList)
{
    #Get the image information
    $image = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap $ImageFile.Fullname
    #Get the image attributes
    $ImageHeight = $image.Height
    $ImageWidth = $image.Width
    #Close the image
    $image.Dispose()
    If($ImageWidth -lt $ImageHeight)
    {
        Move-Item -LiteralPath $ImageFile.FullName -Destination $PortraitPath -Force
    }
}

I tried
$ImageList = Get-ChildItem "*.jp*g" -Recurse

but that ended up putting all the images from the subfolders in a portrait folder in the parent folder...
Thanks
(Credit to https://powershelladministrator.com/2021/09/20/move-images-based-on-dimension/ for the initial script.)

You can move the logic to create the portrait directory inside the loop, then you can add -Recurse to Get-ChildItem to traverse all child directories and inside the loop you can join the file's .DirectoryName property (gets the absolute path of the file's parent directory) with portrait to create the destination path for each file:
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$jpgs = Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.jp*g' -Recurse
$jpgs | ForEach-Object {
    try {
        $image = [System.Drawing.Bitmap]::new($_.FullName)
        $shouldMove = $image.Width -lt $image.Height
    }
    finally {
        if ($image) {
            $image.Dispose()
        }
    }

    if ($shouldMove) {
        # join the jpg parent directory path with `portrait`
        $portraitPath = Join-Path $_.DirectoryName -ChildPath portrait
        # if the folder doesnt exist
        if (-not (Test-Path $portraitPath)) {
            # create it
            $null = New-Item $portraitPath -ItemType Directory
        }

        # move it to new dir
        $_ | Move-Item -Destination $portraitPath -Force
        Write-Host "Moving '$($_.FullName)' to '$portraitPath'"
    }
}


Thanks for your response, I tried this code and all it does is create a portrait subfolder in the same directory as the script...

@MisterNobody are you sure you're trying this exact answer? I deleted and updated my previous answer

Yes sir, I copied exactly. Just tried again, same behaviour.

@MisterNobody apologies, try with this new version. Just tested it and should work now

Your revision works! Thank you!

@MisterNobody glad it helped :)

Well, not sure about the case details but ordering based on width/height doesn't give total guarantee about the orientation the picture was  taken. No or am I missing smthg ?
